# Use of File Geodatabase uploaded to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase

I have a few feature classes in a file geodatabase. Instead of uploading the feature classes to ArcGIS Online individually as shapefile, I was trying to upload the entire zipped geodatabase to ArcGIS Online.

```
MyFGD.gdb
  .FeatCls1
  .FeatCls2
  .FeatCls3
  .FeatCls4
```

The File Geodatabase was uploaded successfully and it was honored File Geodatabase "MyFGD", and only one AGOL Feature Layer with the same name as the FGB was also created and hosted "MyFGD".

However, I could not Open the hosted Feature Layer to Map Viewer. It failed with a "Invalid URL" error msg.

How can we add the feature classes in a file geodatabase uploaded to ArcGIS Online to Map Viewer?

Are those feature classes published and hosted on ArcGIS Online individually as AGOL Feature Layer?

Comment: Have you tried adding the local data to ArcMap save MXD and then File - Share As - Service and publish to AGOL. The data will then be uploaded to AGOL.

Comment: Were there any other files accidently included in the zipped gdb? There could have been a publishing issue of the feature layer, I would double check the zipped gdb.

Comment: But I am still keen to know why the uploaded file geodatabase didn't work as feature layer at all.